# Looping over two lists using zip() to add numbers to another list

Tags: python, zip

I have two sets of data here:

```
data_feb = ['1st February', 45, 68, 70, 61, 54, 80, 72, 69, 73, 72, 58, 72, 64, 45, 42]
data_aug = ['1st August', 19, 27, 41, 42, 9, 14, 29, 34, 25, 29, 44, 43, 6, 17]
```

I loop over it to create another list here:

```
for i in data_feb:
    #
    if type(i) == int:
        feb_numbers.append(i)
for i in data_aug:
    if type(i) == int:
        aug_numbers.append(i)
```

But here i have an algorithm to sort them:

```
feb_zero_to_ten = []
feb_ten_to_twenty = []
feb_twenty_to_thirty = []
feb_thirty_to_forty = []
feb_forty_to_fifty = []
feb_fifty_to_sixty = []
feb_sixty_to_seventy = []
feb_seventy_to_eighty = []
feb_eighty_to_ninety = []
feb_ninety_to_hundred = []

aug_zero_to_ten = []
aug_ten_to_twenty = []
aug_twenty_to_thirty = []
aug_thirty_to_forty = []
aug_forty_to_fifty = []
aug_fifty_to_sixty = []
aug_sixty_to_seventy = []
aug_seventy_to_eighty = []
aug_eighty_to_ninety = []
aug_ninety_to_hundred = []

# for loop to iterate over months numbers, sorting them into their correct columns by the 'tens' digit
for i, j in zip(feb_numbers, aug_numbers):
    if 0 <= i < 10 and 0 <= j < 10:
        feb_zero_to_ten.append(i)
        aug_zero_to_ten.append(j)
    elif 10 <= i < 20 and 10 <= j < 20:
        feb_ten_to_twenty.append(i)
        aug_ten_to_twenty.append(j)
    elif 20 <= i < 30 and 20 <= j < 30:
        feb_twenty_to_thirty.append(i)
        aug_twenty_to_thirty.append(j)
    elif 30 <= i < 40 and 30 <= j < 40:
        feb_thirty_to_forty.append(i)
        aug_thirty_to_forty.append(j)
    elif 40 <= i < 50 and 40 <= j < 50:
        feb_forty_to_fifty.append(i)
        aug_forty_to_fifty.append(j)
    elif 50 <= i < 60 and 50 <= j < 60:
        feb_fifty_to_sixty.append(i)
        aug_fifty_to_sixty.append(j)
    elif 60 <= i < 70 and 60 <= j < 70:
        feb_sixty_to_seventy.append(i)
        aug_sixty_to_seventy.append(j)
    elif 70 <= i < 80 and 70 <= j < 80:
        feb_seventy_to_eighty.append(i)
        aug_seventy_to_eighty.append(j)
    elif 80 <= i < 90 and 80 <= j < 90:
        feb_eighty_to_ninety.append(i)
        aug_eighty_to_ninety.append(j)
    elif 90 <= i < 100 and 90 <= j < 100:
        feb_ninety_to_hundred.append(i)
        aug_ninety_to_hundred.append(j)
```

This approach using zip() is not working. I am wondering if using this approach is not worth it, also I am trying to make this code as efficient as possible so any pointers would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: you didn't sort the individual lists so your zip will contain things like `(45, 19)` which doesn't fit anywhere. even if you DID sort them you will end up with things like `(45, 6)` which also doesn't fit anywhere. this is not a good approach

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? First you make two new arrays without the strings. And then you add it to a number of arrays again? Why do you need these 'columns' as you call them?

Answer (score 0):

```
data_feb = ['1st February', 45, 68, 70, 61, 54, 80, 72, 69, 73, 72, 58, 72, 64, 45, 42]
data_aug = ['1st August', 19, 27, 41, 42, 9, 14, 29, 34, 25, 29, 44, 43, 6, 17]
feb_numbers=[i for i in data_feb if isinstance(i,int) ]
aug_numbers=[i for i in data_aug if isinstance(i,int) ]
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(aug_numbers),key=lambda x :x//10)]
```

Output:

```
[[6, 9], [14, 17, 19], [25, 27, 29, 29], [34], [41, 42, 43, 44]]
```

You can use `itertools groupby` to group those numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed here. you test that both `i` and `j` are BOTH in a range but if you look at your numbers you will see that might not happen, thing like `(45, 19)` do not fit in any of the `if`s. If you look at the logic you are trying to achieve then you will notice that you actually want to separate you number by their leading digit (the tens), An easy approach is to make buckets and fill them like this:

```
feb_buckets = [[] for item in range(10)] #  this makes a list of 10 buckets (lists)
aug_buckets = [[] for item in range(10)]
for feb, aug in zip(feb_numbers,aug_numbers):
    feb_bucket[feb//10].append(feb) #  // is integer division (which rounds down)
    aug_bucket[aug//10].append(aug)
```

once you understand the logic you can then simplify the code even further by taking @ajay approach and using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't create all list by hand, just create list of lists and then access them by index.
- For numbers in range `0` to `10` use `feb[0]` to `10` to `20` `feb[1]` etc.
- If you don't know if the lists will have the same length, use function `find_in_range` for each list.

You can use this code below for this:

```
data_feb = ['1st February', 45, 68, 70, 61, 54, 80, 72, 69, 73, 72, 58, 72, 64, 45, 42]
data_aug = ['1st August', 19, 27, 41, 42, 9, 14, 29, 34, 25, 29, 44, 43, 6, 17]

#Dont create all list by hand, just create list of lists and then acces them by index
feb = [[] for i in range(10)] 
aug = [[] for i in range(10)]

def find_in_range(in_list, out_list):
    for x in sorted(in_list[1:]): #exclude the first index, because it is a string
        for i in range(10):
            if  i*10 < x < (i+1)*10:
                out_list[i].append(x)

find_in_range(data_feb, feb)
find_in_range(data_aug, aug)

print("Feb: ", feb)
print("Aug", aug)
```

This is the output:

```
Feb:  [[], [], [], [], [42, 45, 45], [54, 58], [61, 64, 68, 69], [72, 72, 72, 73], [], []]
Aug [[6, 9], [14, 17, 19], [25, 27, 29, 29], [34], [41, 42, 43, 44], [], [], [], [], []]
```

As you can see the first four arrays of `feb` list are empty because in the list `data_feb` were not any numbers between 0-40.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to accomplish the sort is by having a sorted list of lists. The final output would be `fed_sorted` and `aug_sorted`. The `i-th` list would be in range of `[i*10, (i+1)*10)`.

```
data_feb = ['1st February', 45, 68, 70, 61, 54, 80, 72, 69, 73, 72, 58, 72, 64, 45, 42]
data_aug = ['1st August', 19, 27, 41, 42, 9, 14, 29, 34, 25, 29, 44, 43, 6, 17]

feb_numbers = [x for x in data_feb if type(x) == int]
aug_numbers = [x for x in data_aug if type(x) == int]

GROUP_SIZE = 10  # 0-9, 10-19, 20-29....

feb_sorted = [[x for x in feb_numbers if x in range(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10)] for i in range(GROUP_SIZE)]
aug_sorted = [[x for x in aug_numbers if x in range(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10)] for i in range(GROUP_SIZE)]

print(feb_sorted)
print(aug_sorted)
```

Answer (score -1):

The first part of your code can be made more effecient like so:

```
data_feb = ['1st February', 45, 68, 70, 61, 54, 80, 72, 69, 73, 72, 58, 72, 64, 45, 42]
data_aug = ['1st August', 19, 27, 41, 42, 9, 14, 29, 34, 25, 29, 44, 43, 6, 17]


data_feb  = [x for x in data_feb if x == int]
data_aug = [x for x in data_aug if x == int]
```

For the second part it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to give some more background? Why do you need this many lists? What do you mean by sorting them and why do you need them sorted in this way?